# Stopping watchdog timer from global object constructor

Tags: c++, initialization, watchdog

I am integrating a number of C drivers into a C++ integrated embedded project.
Moving to the OOP approach, I organize functions and variables into classes, each one representing a system module.

Declaring global objects, compiler RTS library startup code is included to build them up using their constructors before program execution reaches `main()`.
This delays watchdog_timer disabling, which is called from `main()`, so the system doesn't boot up.

I have a single global object containing other objects as members, each one with its non-trivial constructor; stopping watchdog timer at the beginning of global object constructor doesn't solve the issue.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: I suggest a redesign to minimise use of globals. Global objects introduce a whole bunch of concerns, such as unspecifed order of construction.  I'd create all the objects in `main()` after disabling the watchdog timer. That also allows you to explicitly control the order of construction of objects more easily. That does mean you'll need to find a way to pass the objects (or pointers/references to them) to code that needs them, but that is relatively simple in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `WatchDog` class that handles starting, stopping and kicking it. If you must use a big global then instantiate `WatchDog` as the first member. It's constructor should turn off the watchdog. In `main` you can start it when all is ready to run.

Agree with comment that having a giant global class is a bad code smell. I've done a bunch of embedded systems both big and small without needing to use globals.

Comment: How did you manage Interrupt handlers to access objects members? Avoiding a single giant class sounds wise to me, but I need to use globals/global pointers to make functions like: extern void TA0_N_IRQHandler (void) __attribute__((weak,alias("Default_Handler"))); access members.

Comment: That's a difficult question to answer because of multiple factors. How big is your system? How does that processor's compiler handle interrupts? (Which you've shown.) Is there an RTOS? In the limited space of a comment it can't be addressed sufficiently and SO wouldn't like a long comment thread to address it. One basic approach is a global lever interrupt function that records the data and sets a flag. When you need data you check the flag to see if there is new data, read it, and reset the flag. The compiler might let you do that with a static class member function to encapsulate the data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be solved if the same instruction is executed at the beginning of the first member object constructor, which is called before the container class one.

Let's take a class like:

```
class A
{
    object B;
    object C;
    object D;
    // ...

public:
    A(void);
    // ...
};

A::A()
{
    Stop_WatchDog();
    // ...
}
```

A code like the one below would reproduce the issue:

```
A myContainerObject;

int main()
{
   Stop_WatchDog();
}
```

Unless `B` is changed as:

```
class B
{
    // ...
public:
    B(void);
    // ...
}

B::B()
{
    Stop_WatchDog();
    // ...
}
```

So, in general, the watchdog timer should be stopped at the beginning of the first member constructor of program first-initialized global object.

Comment: The reason for what you're seeing is that the constructor of all members (`B`, `C`, `D`, etc) are called before the constructor of the containing `A`.   If you need the watchdog timer stopped in order to construct objects, then you need to guarantee that no object is constructed before the watchdog timer is stopped.   That doesn't happen in the constructor of `A`, because it comes after other constructors.